# Solving a system of equations for an array of unknowns

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I'd like to solve a system of equations (11 equations). To do that I'm thinking about creating an array of 11 unknowns. Can I feed it to a `Solve` solver then? Or should I list all the 11 elements of the array?

Moreover, since 11 equations are quite a lot, can I define the equations beforehand and then just provide the `Solve` with the names, instead of writing down the equations all inside the solver? That would allow also a much easier handling of the equations themselves.

Comment: How about `ClearAll[x,y]; eqns = {x == 2 y, y^2 == 5 x};
variables = {x, y};
Solve[eqns, variables]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes to both your questions. Here is an example with three equations. I'm sure you can generalize it to 11.

```
Clear[u]
vars = Array[u, 3];
eqns = {3 u[1] + 2 u[2] == 1, u[1] + u[3] == 0, u[2] - 2 u[3] == 0};
Solve[eqns, vars]
```

> `{{u[1] -> -1, u[2] -> 2, u[3] -> 1}}`